# Parallel execution of same job with different configuration- pipeline jenkinsfile script path is updated incorrect

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkinsfile

I have a jenkins job **A** and i have 5 tests (each triggering job **A** with updation of different jenkinsfile script path as Before Each test) executing in **parallel**

- Test1 with pipeline-jenkinfile-1
- Test2 with pipeline-jenkinfile-2
- Test3 with pipeline-jenkinfile-3
- Test4 with pipeline-jenkinfile-4
- Test5 with pipeline-jenkinfile-5

When I start the tests in parallel, I can see 5 instance of same job getting triggered but **each test is updated with incorrect jenkinsfile.**

- Test**1** with pipeline-**jenkinfile-4**
- Test**2** with pipeline-**jenkinfile-3**
- Test3 with pipeline-jenkinfile-1
- Test4 with pipeline-jenkinfile-5
- Test5 with pipeline-jenkinfile-2

Running on same node - NODE A

Test 1 Before step: Updating the jenkins job pipeline jenkinsFile script path using API

```
curl -X POST http://developer:developer@localhost:8080/job/test/config.xml --data-binary "@mymodifiedlocalconfig.xml"
```

And i trigger the job with buildwithParameters using rest api

```
curl -X POST http://USER:API_TOKEN@localhost:8080/job/test/build --data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"paramA", "value":"123"}]}'
```

How to fix this such a way in parallel execution test update with correct jenkinsfile?